# Vanishing covariant derivative of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, vector-fields, connections

I'm asked to prove the following statement in my physics book:

> A vector field with covariant components $v^b$, in order to have a vanishing covariant derivative everywhere in a manifold, must satisfy: $$(\partial_b\Gamma^{d}{}_{ac}-\partial_c\Gamma^{d}{}_{ab}+\Gamma^{e}{}_{ac}\Gamma^{d}{}_{eb}-\Gamma^{e}{}_{ab}\Gamma^{d}{}_{ec})v^a=0$$

I've tried taking the covariant derivative $\nabla_av^b=\partial_a v^b+\Gamma^b{}_{ca}v^c$ and equating this to zero, and I think I might be able to get something by taking double derivatives, since it would be a way to get the gamma coefficients derived... But I haven't been able to get anything clear. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The expression in the parenthesis looks like the Ricci curvature (first sight, not 100% sure).

Comment: @Yuval It is not the Ricci curvature. It is actually the Riemann tensor.

Comment: Yes I see, there are 4 indices not contracted.

Comment: If you can check the expression is the Riemann curvature, then you can prove it by changing coordinate: we can assume $V$ never vanish, therefore we can assume $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$. It is then straightforward to check $\langle R(X, Y)V, W\rangle=0$ for all $X, Y, W$.

Comment: I think I see how that works... But I think that's quite above my level, since we haven't yet seen anything about the Riemann curvature tensor. I guess I need to find a more "brute" solution... Thanks anyway! It gave me some starting point

Comment: Maybe try to compute out $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}}\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_b}} V-\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_b}}\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}} V$ in local coordinates; since $V$ is parallel, the result must be $0$. I think this gives the desired equation.